# if a column has duplicates and next column has a value how to add these to duplicate values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Their is a dataframes with the columns, below is input ,if the username has duplicates and the owner region should be added to the duplicates also

```
Queue    Owner Region   username
 xxy                     aan
 xyz      india           aan
 yyx                      aandiapp
 xox       UK            aandiapp
 yox      china       aashwins
 zxy                  aashwins
 yoz        aus       aasyed
 zxo                 aasyed
```

The required output should be

```
Queue   Owner Region   username
 xxy      india        aan
 xyz    india          aan
 yyx       Uk          aandiapp
 xox       Uk         aandiapp
 yox      china       aashwins
 zxy      china       aashwins
 yoz        aus       aasyed
 zxo        aus       aasyed
```

please anyone  help me , Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1):

I think need replace empty values to `NaN`s first and then per groups repalce them by forward and back filling:

```
df['Owner Region'] = df['Owner Region'].replace('', np.nan)
df['Owner Region'] = df.groupby('username')['Owner Region'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

Comment: @Onyambu - by copying

Comment: import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\c_ssaiva\Desktop\useralias.xlsx")
data2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\c_ssaiva\Desktop\useraliasregions.xlsx")
df2_new = pd.concat([data,data2] , sort=True ,ignore_index=True).sort_values('username')                df['Owner Region'] = df['Owner Region'].replace('', np.nan)
      df['Owner Region'] = df.groupby('username')['Owner Region'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())    i am getting error df is not defined

Comment: must you save it in excel before reading? Or you red from the clipboard?

Comment: @vastalayaram - need change `df2_new = pd.concat([data,data2] , sort=True ,ignore_index=True).sort_values('username')` to `df= pd.concat([data,data2] , sort=True ,ignore_index=True).sort_values('username')`

Comment: Or change in my solution `df` to `df2_new`

Comment: @vastalayaram - Because DataFrame assigned to variable with name `df` in my solution, in your to `df2_new`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mask` and `groupby`.

```
df['Owner Region'] = (
   df['Owner Region']
     .mask(df['Owner Region'].str.len().eq(0))
     .groupby(df.username)
     .ffill()
     .bfill())
```

```
df
  Queue Owner Region  username
0   xxy        india       aan
1   xyz        india       aan
2   yyx           UK  aandiapp
3   xox           UK  aandiapp
4   yox        china  aashwins
5   zxy        china  aashwins
6   yoz          aus    aasyed
7   zxo          aus    aasyed
```

When you call `groupby` + `ffill`, the subsequent `bfill` call does not require a groupby.

---

If it is possible a group is only NaNs in it, you cannot avoid the `apply`...

```
df['Owner Region'] = (
   df['Owner Region']
        .mask(df['Owner Region'].str.len().eq(0))
       .groupby(df.username)
       .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
```

```
df
  Queue Owner Region  username
0   xxy        india       aan
1   xyz        india       aan
2   yyx           UK  aandiapp
3   xox           UK  aandiapp
4   yox        china  aashwins
5   zxy        china  aashwins
6   yoz          aus    aasyed
7   zxo          aus    aasyed
```

Comment: @jezrael No worries at all

Comment: oops, it is wrong, need ` .ffill()
     .bfill()` with apply, because else `bfill` working with `Series`

Comment: @jezrael The bfill doesn't need to be in an apply. Let me test it.

Comment: with general solution need it, because possible data repalced from another group

Comment: @jezrael No, the previous ffill will ensure that data is forward filled upto the end of the previous group. So the next bfill does not need to be in a groupby. That's my point. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, but if only `NaN` groups ?